# Is there a way to check overview button?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am developing an app where there is a left Drawer on the Home screen. The drawer fits perfectly on most devices, but on some devices, the drawer is covered whether the screen has overview button(phone without physical button, using on screen button) or its swallowed under the bottom of the screen(mostly happen on Xiaomi, and yes, i've tried on 5 xiaomi phones).This also happening on the emulator from android studio. The Question is, can the app knows if there a overview button on the phone , so the app can be developed to put the layout on top(not covering) of it. Or is there another way, more simple and efficient?

Here is the layout code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
<!-- *********** NAVIGATION DRAWER *********** -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@color/drawerColor"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/drawer_user_padding_left"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/drawer_user_padding_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/drawer_user_padding_top_newest"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/referal_ID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/nav_fontsize"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="\nReferal ID: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/content_fontsize"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/userdata_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/theme"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/drawer_user_padding_left"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/drawer_separator_margin_top"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/drawer_user_padding_bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/content_fontsize"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/content_fontsize"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="email@email.com" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_point"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/magno_coin"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_credit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="@dimen/content_fontsize"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="0"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/upper_nav"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_upper_nav_margin"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

            </ListView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/upper_separator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_separator_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_separator_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/drawer_separator_margin_bottom"
                android:background="@color/contentColor"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/middle_nav"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:scrollbars="none">
            </ListView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/middle_separator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_separator_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_separator_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/drawer_separator_margin_bottom"
                android:background="@color/contentColor"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lower_nav"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:scrollbars="none">
            </ListView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/lower_separator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_separator_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_separator_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/drawer_separator_margin_bottom"
                android:background="@color/contentColor"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/item_margin"
                android:scrollbars="none">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_separator_height"
            android:background="@color/theme"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_version"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/item_space_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/item_space_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/version_margin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/smaller_fontsize"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="ver 1.0.0"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout></android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: On the picture i scrolled down until cant be scrolled anymore]

On the picture i scrolled down until cant be scrolled anymore

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if I dont understand your question.

I dont see in your xml `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` - its container for drawer content. You need to add `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` to your app dependencies to use NavigationView.

And if you want to do static header for your drawer, there is `app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"` property, where `nav_header` is your header layout.

For other items there are `app:menu="@menu/drawer_view` property, where `drawer_view` is your drawers menu. In this menu you can put as many items as you wish and they will be scrollable if needed. Also you can design it as you want and they are easy for handling in `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

See this Googles [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer) for more details. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. Place a listview (or more) inside a scrollview is not good. If you have a finite number of elements I suggest you to build your view programmatically (use addView).

However if you don't want to change your code read that: [list view inside scrollview](https://medium.com/@skidanolegs/listview-inside-scrollview-solve-the-problem-a06fdff2a4e0).

Basically you need to calculate the real height of the listview for every item (**getMeasuredHeight**) after **notifyDataSetChanged**. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent overlapping by Bottom Soft NavigationBar add this to your styles.xml in a values-v21 dir (if dir not exist, create one and copy same styles.xml file from value):

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

Like this eg -

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    .....
    .....

</style>
```

Comment: i tried this ,it seems working.Will this also work with higher API level?

Comment: but, it made my customized theme color wont apply

Comment: Will this also work with higher API level?>> i did not tested, but i think it should work on higher level API too.